# Primality test similar to Pocklington

Tags: number-theory, primality-test

I'm working on a series of number theory proofs and I'm stumped on this one. The idea is to extend each result for the subsequent proof. I just succeeded in proving the following:

Suppose $n > 1$. The number $n$ is prime if and only if there exists a number $b$ such that gcd$(b, n) = 1$ and $b^{n−1} ≡ 1$ (mod $n$) and $b^{(n−1)/d} \not ≡ 1$ (mod $n$) for all positive divisors $d$ of $n − 1$ with $d > 1$.

My proof for this theorem is straightforward: we know that if $n$ is not prime, then for any $b$ we have $exp_n(b) < n-1$ since $exp_n(b)$ must divide $\phi(n) < n-1$. However, if $n$ is prime, we know $\phi(n) = n-1$ and that $n$ must have a primitive root. Therefore if we call $b$ that primitive root, we know that $exp_n(b) = \phi(n) = n-1$.

The proof I'm currently stuck on is as follows:

Suppose $n > 2$. Prove that $n$ is prime iff there exists a number $b$ such that:

1. gcd($b, n$) $= 1$
2. $b^{(n−1)/2} \equiv −1$ (mod $n$)
3. $b^{(n−1)/q} \not \equiv 1 $(mod $n$) for all odd prime divisors $q$ of $n − 1$.

I know that this is related to the [Pocklington criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test), and I see that $b^{(n−1)/2} \equiv −1$ (mod $n$) is equivalent to $b^{n−1} \equiv 1$ (mod $n$). So I'm stuck on (3); I'm not sure I see how the previous result applies when only considering odd prime divisors. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: Be careful, $b^\frac{n-1}{2} \equiv -1$ is not equivalent to $b^{n-1} \equiv 1$

Comment: But if the first equivalence holds, the second also holds.

Comment: Thank you - that's true. More correctly, $b^{n-1} \equiv 1$ iff $b^{(n-1)/2} \equiv \pm 1$. Still struggling with this proof though - any other hints?

Comment: Think about the order of $b$ with respect to $n$. This is the least number $u>0$ with $b^u\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$. $n$ is prime if and only if there is a b with $ord_b(n)=n-1$

Comment: In other words, $n$ is prime if and only if $b^u\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$ is true only for $u\equiv 0\ (\ mod\ (n-1)\ )$ for some $b$